# Где вы берёте шаблоны для своих сайтов?

Tags: вёрстка

А где вы берёте шаблоны для своих проектов?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.templatemonster.com/ru/ - много различных платных шаблонов под разные cms
если нужны бесплатные - то поисковики по фразе "бесплатный шаблон для нужной cms"

Answer (score 1):

Тут вариантов несколько:

1. Заказать у какого-то верстальщика нужный шаблон. Если верстальщик профессионал, то шаблон будет высокого качества, работать единобразно в разных браузерах и также полностью отвечать Вашим требованиям.
2. Разработать самому шаблон. Этот вариант подходит, если Вы сами хорошо умеете сочетать в себе качества верстальщика, дизайнера, проектировщика, а в дальнейшем и программиста, так как логику сайта тоже писать будете Вы.
3. Скачать готовый платный или бесплатный шаблон. Бесплатные шаблоны можно найти на одном из предложенных мною ресурсов: [www.free-css.com](http://www.free-css.com), [www.ftemplate.ru](http://www.ftemplate.ru), [html-templates.info](http://html-templates.info). Таких сайтов очень много, перечислять можно долго, потому пользуйтесь поисковиками).

P.S. Успехов Вам в создании или нахождении нужного шаблона сайта).